# Internal Storage Running Out

Tags: storage

Okay, so a couple weeks ago I bought a 32 GB micro SD card. When I installed it, I moved all my music, pictures, and videos to it -- all together, they were about 3 or 4 GBs. So I thought I'd get back those 3 or GBs of internal storage, but I didn't??? My internal storage still read as "Available Space: 500 mbs". Recently, I uninstalled about ten apps that I downloaded previously, yet I didn't receive that space back either. So I should have about 5 GBs of internal storage left, right? I've either deleted or moved everything to my micro SD card, but I keep getting the notification "Storage Running Out". Please help.

Comment: Did you just move it, or also delete it?

Comment: What I mean by "delete", I mean I uninstalled some apps. I moved everything that I could to my SD card.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of "fake cards" out there. I recently boughtone that was imprinted as a 64Gb card, but it had only about 6 Gb available. You can tell if that's the case with yours by the use of a program (or rather a set of scripts) called "F3".  Here's the link. http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/   Read about it before you download it.  It is designed for Linux, but can be run under Windows using Cygwin.

If you are using linux, there is also an experimental "f3fix" to make the fake card  useable, but at its true useable capacity.

I have used the first two scripts, with pretty quick results. I have not used "f3probe" or "f3fix"

By the way, if you are not using linux, I highly recommend that you try it. It's really not much of a learning curve to get started with Mint17 or with Ubuntu, and you don't have to change or delete anything about your Windows installation. You can install it right along side of your current windows installation, and at boot time choose which you want to run.